# Data binding to Mustache templates? (preferably clean and simple)

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mustache

What I am after is a piece of code that could provide me a clean and simple one-way solution to bind the changes from DOM to the object that is used to render it.

Example: And object

```
{name: 'Joe'}
```

is used to render the Mustache template

```
<div><input val="{{name}}" /></div>
```

How can I match the change event in the inputfield to the correct property?

What about iterations?

```
{{#users}}
<div><input val="{{name}}" /></div>
{{/users}}
```

Is there a such thing?

Edit: And yes, I am aware of Backbone, Angular, Ember, younameit. However, what I need is a specific case to Mustache/Handlebars.

Comment: [http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) specifies how to handle empty lists (empty check) and non-empty lists iteration exactly as you've specified. Have you given tested your code?

Comment: I am aware of empty lists etc. What I am after is data binding.

Comment: By binding if you mean bi-directional binding, take a look at AngularJS as vittore suggested. Mustache simply renders the template with a pass over it given your object.

Comment: You should probably add a requirement to your question that you're not willing to use AngularJS, Ember, Backbone or any other library that implements data binding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, managed to find a way to do simple data binding via shadow dom solution. It's not the perfect solution but it will do for now.

Comment: I thought shadow dom is experimental and not widely supported.

Comment: Well, maybe shadow dom was wrong term. Mayhaps shadow dom-like solution would be the correct - replicating the dom structure to memory and doing the data binding in there.

Comment: that is something that devs have been doing with jQuery for 8 years..it's just normal programing, there is no term for this since it's so basic..

Comment: Well, it's not your basic solution, rather than more of a simulation in the context of given data but whatever, as long as I got it working it's enough for me. For now, at least.

Answer (score 11):

Ractive is exactly this. Mustache with data binding. https://ractive.js.org

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for called [Angular.js](http://angular.js)

There is little bit different approach in other similar frameworks like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com), batman.js etc.

Check [sample todo application](http://todomvc.com/) to see how different framework do it.

**UPDATE:**

On the other hand, if all your "bindings" are going to be simple and you do not care much about syntax there are two approaches that you can use with just jquery in order to minimize ammount of code working with input fields:

1. one input field per model field and just one model

```js
var model = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
$('#myForm').on('blur', 'input', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    field = $this.data('model')
  model[field] = $this.val()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myForm'>
  <input type='text' data-model='a' />
  <input type='text' data-model='b' />
  <input type='text' data-model='c' />
</form>
```

2. kinda extension of first one you can grouping elements together if you have multiple models and multiple fields per model. Good example is table editor, when each row bound to element in array and has several fields bound to cells in a row

js

```
var models = { modelA : {...}, modelB: {...}}

$('#myForm').on('blur', 'input', function(e) {
   var $this = $(this), field = $this.data('field')
   , model = $this.data('model') 
   // last line can be smth like $this.closest('div.group').data('model')

   models[model][field] = $this.val()   
})
```

So to sum up your example:

```
 {{#users}}
   <div><input data-model='users' data-index='{{ $index }}' val="{{name}}" /></div>
 {{/users}} 

 $('#myForm').on('blur', 'input', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), index = $this.data('index')
    , model = $this.data('model') 
    window.data[model][index][field] = $this.val()   
 })
```

Comment: +1 That's what I was going to answer. Specifically, check out this tutorial (http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-binding).

Comment: Nope. I am well aware of Backbone, Angular, Ember etc. What I am after is simple one way binding frmo the rendered inputs to object.

Comment: @crappish Mustache isn't designed to handle data binding. You could use jQuery to read the input process the partial template and inject in into the html element but you'd essentially be re-implementing what AngularJS is designed to support by default.

Comment: Unless you're reeeealy concerned about adding another library, there isn't really a good argument for re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: @vittore This is close to what I have been testing, however, A) I would prefer not to pollute the DOM with extra properties and B) still being able to handle iterations and such, which seems to be a bit of PITA. I guess only thing left is to parse the template for Mustache variables :P

Comment: @Evan, I am aware and I am not asking for "a way to do this", rather than specifically how to do this with Mustache (or Handlebars, if you will). If it would have data bindings, this question would not exist, now would it. Same thing if I would simply be after data bindings. ;) You could say I'm trying to recreate same behavior, however, as stated, what I need is simple one way binding from the DOM to the JS. I'd rather have actual answers (like vittore here) than smartass comments about "lol, you are doing it wrong".

Answer (score 1):

Check [jtmpl](http://jtmpl.com), it should exactly fit your need—render a Mustache template and keep DOM synchronized with model at all times.

Collections and node attributes are supported and your example syntax should work as is (just correct "val" -> "value").

Comment: Whoa! That looks mighty fine and exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I'll check it out and if it matches, I'll accept this as an aswer. :) (oh and yeah, probably should be "value" :D)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fit my bill either as it also does the data rendering which I need to have separately in this case. :/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at `vue.js` - it's now a widely adopted framework and is much lighter than Angular (600kb vs 60kb minified and 20kb if gzipped) and uses mustache-similar syntax.